# Adsense Stopped Showing Ads after Angularjs used

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, adsense

I have an Asp.net mvc site with Google adsense enabled with scripts added in the Layout.cs and contents getting generated via ajax and jquery from api. Everything was working fine and ads where showing

Recently I had added a new page where I used angularjs for databinding using CDN .and the page is working well.but ads stopped showing up. only on that page.the message showing on console is

> The resource http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/r20190313/r20190131/show_ads_impl.js was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.

And in Layout.cs

```
 <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <script>
        (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({
            google_ad_client: "ca-pub-1771190807684402",
            enable_page_level_ads: true
        });
    </script>

Adding URL of my Site for reference
```

[JumptoJob-Online exam](http://www.jumb2job.com/OnlineTest/Test/TestEngine)

> And my angularjs controller for page looks simple

```
   <script>
    "use strict";

    /*We need to manually start angular as we need to
    wait for the google charting libs to be ready*/

    var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['googlechart']);
    mainApp.controller('QuestionController', myControllerFunction);
    myControllerFunction.$inject = ["$scope", "$http", "$timeout"];


    function myControllerFunction($scope, $http, $timeout) {
}
      </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted adsense support and provided the URL.they asked me to wait for some hours and then ad start showing. asper them its always better to use adsense directive with angularjs than just using normal adsense script and auto ads